# External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'mybatis-3-mapper.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed with Quarkus native

Tags: mybatis, quarkus

I'm tring to use mybatis in a Quarkus project built in docker native mode. When I load an xml mapping file, the following errore is raised:

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 108; External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'mybatis-3 -mapper.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.
  at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:263)                                                                                                                               
  at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.(XPathParser.java:127)                                                                                                                                       
  at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.(XMLMapperBuilder.java:81)
```

The code snippet that I use to load the mapping file is:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
String mapperResourceName = "mybatis/test.xml";
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(mapperResourceName);
XMLMapperBuilder mapperParser = new XMLMapperBuilder(inputStream, configuration, mapperResourceName,
                        configuration.getSqlFragments());
mapperParser.parse();
MappedStatement  mappedStatement = configuration.getMappedStatement("test");
BoundSql boundSql = mappedStatement.getBoundSql(params);
```

while the mapper file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="Test">
    <select id="test" >
        SELECT t
        FROM Test t
    </select>
</mapper>
```

I have already tried to add

```
<quarkus.native.additional-build-args>-J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
```

without success.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `http` with `https`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to solve the problem: in the Dockerfile.native file it is necessary to add -Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all on application launching.

You can find the re-producer project at https://github.com/draccagni/quarkus-hibernate-orm-mybatis-3